# Only allow administrators to bypass required reviews, and not bypass entire PR process

Tags: github, pull-request, protected-branches

We have a GitHub repository to which multiple users have access. The idea is that everyone must create a pull request before merging to the `main` branch, rather than committing and pushing directly to it.

I would like to enable required reviews for most users. I want administrators to still be able to bypass required reviews, *but **not** bypass required pull requests*.

Is this possible with GitHub?